# SQL SERVER 2014 - Memory Full even after set value for "max server memory"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-administration

I'm using SQL server 2014 on a server that has 76GB RAM. the  "max server memory" in SQL is 32 GB, database size is about 600GB.

SQL Memory Consumption hit the 99% and affect the server performance. can I know the reason?

thank you.

Comment: what is the reason for setting max memory to 32 gb

Comment: it was 64GB, I changed to 32GB. but the problem still there

Comment: why do you think decreasing memory will alleviate your problem

Comment: because "max server memory" parameter created for this reason

Comment: I think you are missing many things wrt,configuring a server,if you are not running any thing on box except sqlserver,you can leave 5% for OS and assign the rest to SQLServer and see if this rectifies your problem.If not you can find queries which are performing poorly(using more memory and tune them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem !!
it was in a procedure that move data from SQL server to MySQL every minutes using Linked server.
linked server activities is not included in "max server memory" for that reason the memory get full.

Comment: You should probably rewrite that procedure then. A simple SSIS package to transfer the data wouldn't have such a problem. I suspect an `INSERT INTO remote.db.... SELECT FROM Local....` wouldn't have that problem either, but SSIS would transfer a stream of data using buffering and batching that can't be specified in an INSERT command